# How do I create a notification when a machine goes offline?

Tags: azure-devops

We have on-prem machines, and a bunch of them when offline, and we didn't know for several days because the pipelines just kept waiting for the machines.  How can we set up an email when they go offline?

Comment: https://morgantechspace.com/2015/07/powershell-check-if-machine-is-up-or-down.html

Answer (score 0):

You could leverage something like the [Azure Logic App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-overview), call the Azure REST API - [Agents - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/agents/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) via the [Http Action](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-native-http) to check the [`TaskAgentStatus`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/agents/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#taskagentstatus), and send some notification like [send an email](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-office365-outlook) when the status is offline.